# Pruebas de hipótesis estadísticas en python

Tags: python, scipy

Necesito implementar pruebas de hipótesis estadísticas en python, como por ejemplo, la prueba de Chi-cuadrado, prueba de diferencias de medias, pruebas de bondad de ajustes de distribuciones y en general eso. Alguien tiene información de un blog, libro o página donde salga explicado bien?. Solo encuentro cosas sueltas mal integradas.

Además me gustaría saber que paquetes desdecargar para poder realizar estas pruebas.

Gracias :D

Comment: No es mi campo, pero los articulos de este blog tienen buena pinta: [1](https://blog.adrianistan.eu/2017/10/31/estadistica-python-pandas-numpy-scipy-parte-i/), [2](https://blog.adrianistan.eu/2017/11/01/estadistica-python-manipulando-datos-pandas-parte-ii/), [3](https://blog.adrianistan.eu/2017/11/04/estadistica-python-media-mediana-varianza-percentiles-parte-iii/) y [4](https://blog.adrianistan.eu/2018/01/17/estadistica-python-ajustar-datos-una-distribucion-parte-vii/) El que habla de prueba de hipótesis es el 4, pero igual hay que mirarse el resto.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D, si en el link 4 está el ejemplo de pruebas de bondad de ajuste que necesitaba muchas gracias :D